# error while loading shared libraries bumblebee

Tags: ubuntu

Pretty simple test in Ubuntu terminal:

```
optirun glxspheres
glxspheres: error while loading shared libraries: libturbojpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Another example:

```
optirun firefox
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libturbojpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? If u want graphic cards details, please tell me which command i need to input in the terminal. Before someone asks: no sudo doesn't solve the problem.

```
primusrun glxspheres
primusrun firefox
```

seems to be working on the other hand.
Note: to get equal frame rate for optirun and primusrun use:

```
vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxspheres
```

Comment: does anyone even know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html

This was what I found with a quick Google search.

Comment: So it was a bug indeed.